# Go: embedded type's field initialization in derived type

Tags: go, embedding

Here is the code that works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Base struct {
    Field  int
}

type Derived struct {
    Base
}

func main() {
    d := &Derived{}
    d.Field = 10
    fmt.Println(d.Field)
}
```

And here's the code that fails to compile with `./main.go:17: unknown Derived field 'Field' in struct literal`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Base struct {
    Field  int
}

type Derived struct {
    Base
}

func main() {
    d := &Derived{
        Field: 10,
    }
    fmt.Println(d.Field)
}
```

What exactly is going on here? Sorry if it's obvious, but I just don't understand.

Comment: Stop using terms like `Base` and `Derived` with Go. Go doesn't have inheritance and you'll just cause yourself grief by trying to think in terms of inheritance in a language which instead embraces composition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the language [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.

So that's why it *doesn't* work.

Here are two possible ways to work around that limitation, each illustrated in the following function:

```
func main() {
    d := &Derived{
        Base{Field: 10},
    }

    e := new(Derived)
    e.Field = 20

    fmt.Println(d.Field)
    fmt.Println(e.Field)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To initialize composed objects you have to initialize the embedded field, like any other object:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Base struct {
    Field int
}

type Derived struct {
    Base
}

func main() {
    d := &Derived{
        Base{10},
    }
    fmt.Println(d.Field)
}
```